# How do I get ngix to stop listening on port 80?

Tags: webserver, nginx

I'm running a node.js webserver on an Amazon Linux EC2, but I can't listen on port 80 because there's an nginx server listening on that port:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-178 server]$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6666              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      934/pm2
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6667              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      934/pm2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27324/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1211/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1251/sendmail
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1211/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               971/dhclient
udp        0      0 172.31.39.178:123           0.0.0.0:*                               1236/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               1236/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               1236/ntpd
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-178 server]$
```

I don't know if I should just delete nginx (Not sure where to find it, if I were to try), or turn it off, or something like that. I don't use an nginx web-server, I guess it came packaged with the Amazon EC2.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
 sudo rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx && rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say right from the start I do not know Amazon Linux EC2, but I did do a bit of research to try and help.

You should be able to stop nginx with:

```
nginx -s stop
```

You should be able to stop it from starting on reboot with:

```
chkconfig nginx off
```

It may be that you need to use sudo to issue both of these commands:

```
sudo nginx -s stop

sudo chkconfig nginx off
```

It may be that you need to use the path:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop

sudo /sbin/chkconfig nginx off
```

I cannot tell you this is the right path, however, this is what I found. If this does not seem to be the right path, you can always use `find`. You may need to use `man find` for specifics.